# Why am I getting an rospy error in __getitem__ raise KeyError(key)?

Tags: rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to launch a python script and hand over a parameter from the launchfile:
script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import roslib
roslib.load_manifest( 'package_name' )

import rospy
import datetime, sys, yaml
from gazebo_msgs.msg import ModelStates

# some functions
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sim = rospy.get_param( '~sim' ) # <- edit

    rospy.init_node('package_name', anonymous=True)
    #something else ...
```

and I am trying to start it like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
    <arg name="sim" default="true"/>

    <node name="node_name" pkg="package_name" type="script.py" output="screen">
        
        <param name="sim" value="$( arg sim )" />
    </node>
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/147931/why-am-i-getting-an-rospy-error-in-__getitem__-raise-keyerror(key)-?/) by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on ROS Answers with karma: 862 on 2014-04-02

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Brendan Andrade](https://answers.ros.org/users/4682/brendan-andrade/) on 2014-04-03**:
import roslib and roslib.load_manifest should not be used if you're using ROS Groovy or later and catkin. Not sure if the inclusion of those lines may be causing your issue.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2018-07-26**:
I ran into this and had simply forgotten that usually I provide a default parameter:

```
foo = rospy.get_param( '~foo', 5.0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know where the problem was now! I was missing the `rospy.init_node()`
So my main should be:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('package_name', anonymous=True)
    sim = rospy.get_param( '~sim' ) # <- edit

    #something else ...
```

---

Originally posted by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) with karma: 862 on 2014-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on 2014-04-09**:
can't mark it as answered :(
but it is ..

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2014-04-09**:
It's probably a bug that trying to get params without calling init_node doesn't raise an error. @William, @Dirk Thomas?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-04-09**:
I'm surprised that doesn't raise an exception.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-04-09**:
The only thing I can imagine is that someone else called `rospy.init_node` in another part of the code and there for the `~` got expanded to something other than `package_name`.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To get a param in the node's namespace, which is what your launchfile will create, use:

```
sim = rospy.get_param( '~sim' )
```

See [getting parameters in python](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Parameter%20Server#Getting_parameters).

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2014-04-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on 2014-04-03**:
Thanks for your answer. I have actually tried this before. Then I get this exception:

20, in 
sim = rospy.get_param( '~sim' )
File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/client.py", line 452, in get_param
return _param_server[param_name] #MasterProxy does all the magic for us
File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/msproxy.py", line 117, in **getitem**
raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: '~sim'

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2014-04-03**:
if you do rosparam list, does the paramater show up?

**Comment by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on 2014-04-08**:
how can i do a rosparam in this namespace? As I understand it, this param only exists in the namespace of the launchfile.

**Comment by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on 2014-04-08**:
And like I said, I edited my question code with the '~' as suggested above. -> same result

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I too had this issue but my problem was not because of rospy init.

Instead I assumed that get_param would just quietly fail if a parameter did not exist (like it does in cpp). However in python for some reason this method raises an error and kills the node if the parameter does not exist (This is a poor design IMO).

So if you're like me and have this issue, use the following:

```
if rospy.has_param('~sim'):
    sim = rospy.get_param('~sim')
```

(I realize this KEY_ERROR is documented on the rospy parameter server page, however coming from roscpp to rospy one assumes the methods behave similarly)

---

Originally posted by [biglotusturtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/30307/biglotusturtle/) with karma: 165 on 2017-10-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-02**:
The [API docs](http://docs.ros.org/lunar/api/rospy/html/rospy-module.html#get_param) for `rospy.get_param()` say:

> Raises:
> ...
>
> - KeyError - if `value` not set and default is not given

It doesn't "kill the node" itself, that's just default Python behaviour with uncaught exceptions.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-02**:
Wrapping everything in a `try: .. catch` would be a way to deal with that.

re: `rospy` vs `roscpp` behaviour: yes, that is a known problem with ROS1, and is one of the reasons why in ROS2 all (official) client libraries will wrap the `C` client library, so we get consistent behaviour.

**Comment by [biglotusturtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/30307/biglotusturtle/) on 2017-10-02**:
Agreed a try: .. catch block would achieve the same functionality but the has_param method is simpler IMO.
I'm interested in this ROS2 implementation. Any info on timeline for that?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-02**:
`try: .. catch` is more 'pythonic' (if you care about that - ask for forgiveness and all that). Less `if: ...` in there.

re: ROS2: see [ros2.org](http://ros2.org). Beta3 was released few weeks ago.

**Comment by [biglotusturtle](https://answers.ros.org/users/30307/biglotusturtle/) on 2017-10-02**:
Thanks @gvdhoorn